# .searchable in sidebar causes cursor to jump to end of text when typing

Tags: swift, search, swiftui, navigation, sidebar

I want to put a search field into the sidebar, but for some reason when using `placement: .sidebar`, the cursor always jumps to the end of the text. So if I want to add a word to the start of the search query, after typing one letter, the cursor jumps to the end.

[image: 1]

Here is some minimal code to reproduce this issue:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = ""
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selection) {
                Text("First")
                    .tag("first")
                
                Text("Second")
                    .tag("second")
                
                Text("Thrid")
                    .tag("third")
            }
        } detail: {
            VStack {
                Text("Detail page for: \(selection)")
                
                Text("Searching for: \(searchText)")
            }
        }
        .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .sidebar)
    }
}
```

macOS version: 13.4.1
Xcode version: 14.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the macOS Sonoma (14.0) update, this problem is now fixed.